# A Choice question discussion

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, vocabulary

We can control floods by creating .........next to rivers. 
a. lakes 
b. dams 
c. seas 
d. bridges 
I believe that the correct answer should be lakes. What do you think should be correct? 
PS: Please provide your answer with explanation, thanks.

Comment: @CookieMonster Explain please? It's a question on vocabulary with somehow logic.

Comment: @CookieMonster It's pretty simple!, I think I should have added preposition tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, dams are built to control the flow of water in rivers and floods happen when there is too much of it in them. Should a flood happen, there is going to be an overflow of water in the river anyway. A dam will do nothing in that case. Moreover, how can a dam be situated next to a river while everybody knows that they're constructed on rivers? Seas are impossible to build because they're gigantic things that man can't create. Bridges go above the water. So, they can't stop floods from happening either. By the method of elimination, this leaves us with *lakes* as the only choice for the right answer. How they can be used as a measure to control floods, I don't know. This is a kind of question that you should ask on a forum that's dedicated specifically to civil engineering rather than asking it on an English-language website.

Comment: but how come that dams are next to rivers? they should be (on) rivers I think or (across) rivers.

Comment: Should I go and choose lakes?

Comment: Yes, that seems like the right answer.

Comment: @MohamedMagdy I can't imagine lakes next to rivers either.

Comment: @dan, Okay what do you think? :D

Comment: @dan This gonna blow my mind.

Comment: @CookieMonster Is there civil engineering section on stack?

Comment: This is the only thing that I was able to find: https://engineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @MohamedMagdy,IMO, the intended answer is *b. dams*. But next to rivers is confusing. According to Wiki: *Reservoirs created by dams not only suppress floods but also provide water for activities such as irrigation, human consumption, industrial use, aquaculture, and navigability*. Refer to this link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dam

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer  is lakes,because next to means near or beside person or things.
Dams are built on rivers.[enter link description here](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/adverbs-of-time-and-frequency/next)

Comment: We've been saying that all along.